# How to properly use std::scoped_lock in an if-statement initializer?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++17

I'm a big fan of C++17's new if-statement initializer syntax and I tend to use it anywhere it makes sense. I also use the new `std::scoped_lock` as well and would like to combine the two new features. However, I can't figure out any "better" syntax than the following:

```
if (std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> guard(mutex_); true) {
  // Do something.
}
```

Note how I have to use the keyword `true` in the conditional side of the if-statement. I would prefer to just put `guard` there but when I try that I get the following error:

> value of type 'std::scoped_lock' is not contextually
>   convertible to 'bool'

`std::scoped_lock` doesn't appear to have any other member functions I could call to get an appropriate boolean value.

Is there any "better" syntax to use than the keyword `true`? Or any other way to make it a bit more clear what's going on? (Or perhaps using `scoped_lock` this way is a bad idea?)

**Edit:**

*I'm aware of the standard practice of just enclosing locks within their own scope by using `{` and `}`. I just happen to prefer this new syntax because I've never been a big fan of a single open-brace out on its own.*

Comment: Just open a new block `{ std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> guard(mutex_); // more code }`.

Comment: Sure, I just happen to prefer the new syntax so that I don't have open braces out on their own. Just a personal preference.

Comment: `#define let(...) if(__VA_ARGS__; true)`?

Comment: If you don't like standalone `{...}`, you may consider `do { ... } while (false)` loop. Or no scope and `unique_lock` with explicit unlock

Comment: @kennyc: "*I tend to use it anywhere it makes sense.*" Since you have no condition, it makes no sense to use an `if` statement. So it doesn't make sense here, and there's no reason to use it.

Comment: You should change your "personal preference" and start using scopes. They are a language feature and enable to do exactly what you want.